# Wordpress get old and new user details on password_reset hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I need to capture the hash password before and after password update. Using

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'updatePassword', 10, 2 );
```

I am able to successfully capture it. How do I achieve it using -

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'resetPassword',10,2)
```

Is there some other method to achieve so the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get old password hash by using wp_get_current_user() on pssword_reset

   ```
   add_action('password_reset', 'resetPassword', 10, 2);

   function resetPassword( $user, $new_pass ) {
       $oldUser = wp_get_current_user();
       //Code for saving your old user data
   }
   ```
2. You can get new password hash on after_password_reset

   ```
   add_action( 'after_password_reset', 'afterResetPassword', 10, 2 );

   function afterResetPassword( $user, $new_pass ) {
      //Code for saving your new user data
   }
   ```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get them at a single place. I need to send both these passwords to an external app on reset/change.

Comment: No I dont think we can get both in one hook.

Answer (score -1):

try the following :

```
<?php

    add_action( 'password_reset', 'my_password_reset', 10, 2 );

    function my_password_reset( $user, $new_pass ) {
        // Do something before password reset.
    }
?>
```

and in the function set the logic that you wish to do

[source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/password_reset)